# Cannot assign a key as an object in the declaration of a JavaScript map

Tags: javascript, maps, key

Map's keys can be any value (including functions, objects, or any primitive).
But why is it wrong then to assign key-value pairs like the way in the code below?

`let myMap=new Map({ {'A':'B'}:{'a':'b'}, {'C':'D'}:{'c':'d'} })`

Answer (score 0):

Because `Map` object take iterable params `new Map([iterable])`
, but Object is non iterable

> The iterable protocol allows JavaScript objects to define or customize their iteration behavior, such as what values are looped over in a for...of construct. Some built-in types are built-in iterables with a default iteration behavior, such as Array or Map, while other types (such as Object) are not.

Please see about iterable

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: Thank you. Well, I feel like I am missing the whole point about maps because I can't see the difference between
`let myMap = new Map([[1, 'one'], [2, 'two'], [3, 'three'],])` and `let myArray = [[1, 'one'], [2, 'two'], [3, 'three']]`

Comment: Well, yes, I can use `myMap.get(2)` and get 'two' but with `meArray.get[2]` it won't work of course. Are there more benefits?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to figure this and I have found this syntax to work:

let myMap=new Map([['A','B'],['a','b']]);

Comment: But this is just an array of arrays...
It is just like let data=[['A','B'],['a','b']]
So, no map is needed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, Vlad, for the clarification. I just misunderstood the idea of maps. Anyway, it would be nice if my syntax could work...